# Бот не банит участников

Tags: python, discord, бот

написал бота на питоне. Сделал что бы он банил участников, но к сожалению просто выдает ошибку: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions`

Исходный код:

```
#import need library and module
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

#defining the prefix to be used to call the function
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
client = discord.Client()


@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: commands.MemberConverter):
    await ctx.guild.ban(member)


#called the bot
bot.run('')
```

Все права у бота есть

Comment: Что по вашему может означать текст ошибки? `Missing Permissions`. Попробуйте сначала загуглить или вбить в переводчик ошибку, а уже потом задавать вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У бота нет роли с соответствующими правами, которая позволяет забанить участника.